# concatenate timestamp to date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have set of timestamps:

```
2020-12-07 21:00:00+00
2020-12-07 22:00:00+00
2020-12-07 23:00:00+00
2020-12-07 00:00:00+00
2020-12-06 01:00:00+00
2020-12-06 02:00:00+00
```

how I can concatenate it to dates?
expected:

```
2020-12-07
2020-12-06
```

Comment: Well, I prefer `cast(col as date)` over `col::date`, longer, but Standard SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would *cast* it to a date and the use `distinct` to get the distinct dates

```
select distinct the_column::date
from the_table
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just convert to a date:

```
select distinct ts::date
```

You could more formally truncate:

```
select distinct date_trunc('day', ts)
```